# Page resources couldn’t be loaded in mobile friendly test (wordpress site)

Tags: seo, google, wordpress, search-engine-indexing, mobile

Hi there to webmasters community.
I have a wordpress site and I just realized a problem. When I run the [mobile friendly test](https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly/result?id=TF97fSrXVCTbTAxO9IeDOA) by google and go to Crawling - http response - more information - page resources it says almost all of them couldn’t be loaded. And I think this is the problem causing my pages not indexing. What can I do to fix it?[image]

Comment: Can you click on each item and see what any additional details about what "other errors" might mean?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller No it is not clickable.